# Boost Asio: Some questions about the tutorial (A synchronous daytime server/client)

Tags: c++, boost, boost-asio

I'm trying to work with Boost Asio instead of RakNet so I was trying to follow along with the examples on the Boost website but I have some questions left unanswered. Here's the link: http://www.boost.org/doc/libs/1_55_0/doc/html/boost_asio/tutorial/tutdaytime1.html

Just a heads up, I got the tutorial working, both the client and the server.

1) Why does the query need the string "daytime"? It's nowhere to be found in the server setup. The client only seems to connect when I'm using that string. (Tried with "test" and it didn't connect)

2) Why don't I need to give the client a port to connect to? Does it search for this port itself or is there and option to set this up manually as well?

Thanks in advance.

Comment: You forgot to put in the link :)

Comment: This other Boost Asio page, not from the Boost documentation, may be helpful: [Serial ports and C++](http://www.webalice.it/fede.tft/serial_port/serial_port.html).

Comment: Thanks. I'll take a look at those links

Answer (score 10, accepted):

```
    tcp::resolver::query query(argv[1], "daytime");
```

This lines resolves an endpoint, where `argv[1]` is the host, and `"daytime"` represents the ***port***. Yeah, that's a little surprising, as you'd expect something like `80` or `443` there. However, what you see is the *service-name* which (like hostnames) can be used instead of a hardcoded port, and gets resolved by the operating system.

If hostnames are resolved via `/etc/hosts`, services are resolved via `/etc/services` (or `C:\WINDOWS\system32\drivers\etc\services` I suppose).

On my system this file contains:

```
daytime     13/tcp
daytime     13/udp
```

So, in fact you *could* just use `"13"` instead of `"daytime"`. Note that this is the *default* port for the *system daytime service*. It "works" because your system answers on that port. (Or because your server is already running and uses that port, I don't know which server you run and how :))

Comment: I was using the server code supplied in the next tutorial and yes, that one uses port 13 so that corresponds to what you're saying. Thank you very much for the answer :)

Comment: Nice clear explanation. Now why couldn't the tutorial have just included that simple explanation instead of leaving a lot of us scratching our heads!

Comment: @S.N. The goal of the documentation is to teach ASIO, not to teach TCP networking stacks. See e.g. [Beej's Guide To Network Programming](http://beej.us/guide/bgnet/output/html/singlepage/bgnet.html) under `5.1. getaddrinfo()` or just search for 'service name'